# Why can't I get access to rawBody in my express request

Tags: express, stripe-payments, body-parser

I'm trying to use req.rawBody so I can verify my stripe signature, this is the code I've included in my main server.js file...

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.json({
    verify: (req, res, buf) => {
      req.rawBody = buf
    }
}))
```

and then this is the code in my stripePaymentRoutes.js file...

```
router.post('/billing/invoice-result', (req, res) => {

    let event
    const signature = req.headers['stripe-signature']
    console.log(req.rawBody)

    try {
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.rawBody, signature, process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET_KEY)
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`)
    }
})
```

When I console.log(req.rawBody), it returns undefined and all of my webhooks go to the catch block, as req.rawBody is undefined so the signature isn't verified. Any ideas why I can't get req.rawBody data?

Comment: This is usually due to the parsing that body-parser is doing. Check out [this issue](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/issues/341) for some possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, from the page taintedzodiac pointed out - I had to add the raw middleware before my json parser like so

```
app.use(<your webhook endpoint>, express.raw({ type: "*/*" })); 
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.json());
```

Then in your webhook endpoint

```
app.post(<your webhook endpoint>, (request, response) => {
    let event = request.body;

    // Only verify the event if you have an endpoint secret defined.
    // Otherwise use the basic event deserialized with JSON.parse
    if (process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET) {
      // Get the signature sent by Stripe
      const signature = request.headers['stripe-signature'];
      try {
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.body, signature, process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(`⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed.`, err.message);
        return response.sendStatus(400);
      }
    }
...
```